# How to create a dynamic, custom React Table Component with action and status buttons

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, dynamic-tables

I am creating an admin panel which is a big project & contains a lot of tables. after creating few tables I have noticed that I am repeating my table code & then I thought of creating my custom table component. as you read my question title I Don't want to use a package, I want to create my own.

My all tables have few same repeated columns like id, Status, Action Buttons (CRUD Buttons).

1. I have Lot of Tables.
2. Keys and Values should be dynamic.

I was able to render table data, But having problems while rendering status & action columns.

[image: I want my data should be rendered like this, Status & Action cols are important]

This is the React Js Code.

```
<div className="app-wrapper">
  <DataTable headings={headings} rows={userData} />    
</div>
```

This is the dummy API data for your reference. KEYS & Values will be different for each table (Obviosly)

```
[
{
    "title": "Data fetched successfully",
    "error": false,
    "total": 5,
    "ListData": [
        {
            "Id": "2229FD72-3D74-41B7-BBC4-ECBFFCC75709",
            "UserTypeStatus": 1,
            "UserTypeName": "Payroll",
            "UserTypeShortName": "PR",
            "UserTypeHierarchyOrder": 5
        },
        {
            "Id": "16184F43-3789-44AC-BB73-C07693533D7E",
            "UserTypeStatus": 1,
            "UserTypeName": "Rahul Payroll",
            "UserTypeShortName": "PR",
            "UserTypeHierarchyOrder": 6
        },
        {
            "Id": "19B923A8-88DE-48B5-BD1A-77AC25B41B34",
            "UserTypeStatus": 1,
            "UserTypeName": "User",
            "UserTypeShortName": "UR",
            "UserTypeHierarchyOrder": 7
        },
        {
            "Id": "8BB60DCB-B3E3-4EF0-8602-F27579FF855A",
            "UserTypeStatus": 1,
            "UserTypeName": "Developer",
            "UserTypeShortName": "DP",
            "UserTypeHierarchyOrder": 8
        },
        {
            "Id": "6BDFA417-0658-451A-BFB2-B5002828A1D9",
            "UserTypeStatus": 1,
            "UserTypeName": "Admin",
            "UserTypeShortName": "AD",
            "UserTypeHierarchyOrder": 9999
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: What problems are you facing exactly? Please provide more context on the matter.

Comment: I want to render the Status & Action buttons (as shown in the picture ) dynamically. but I was not able to do that.

Comment: "Having problems" isn't an adequate description. Please review [ask] and revise to be more specific. In particular, where are you trying to set the buttons? I'd have expected component props for that, or perhaps properties in the data object.

Comment: I have only API data that's it and now I want table as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Table = ()=>{
return(
 <table>
   <tr>
    <th>id<th>
    <th>name<th>
    <th>statut<th>
    <th>action<th>
   </tr>
    {ListData.map((item)=>{
       return <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.id}</td>
      <td>{item.name}</td>
      <td><button>{status}</button></td>
      <td><button>action1</button><button>action2</button></td>
      </tr>
     })}
 </table>
)
}
```

Comment: Your solution is Just for this API. What if there is another Api with different column name? Then I have to change that keys again in New table.

Comment: Please read my question again. I have lot of tables not just a single table. I don't want to keep changing keys in other tables.